# Do I need to call Python in a cron job script?

Tags: scripts, python, cron

I'm trying to run a cron job from a home server that runs Ubuntu 24/7, using a Python script to clear a remote mailbox.

In a folder "scripts" in my home folder, I've put in a Python script, garbage.py.

I've made it executable:

```
chmod +x garbage.py
```

The script is (with the username and password updated to the real username and password):

```
#!/bin/env python3

import imaplib
import ssl
from datetime import datetime
# your IMAP server credentials
IMAP_HOST = 'mail.us.opalstack.com'
IMAP_USER = 'mail_username'
IMAP_PASS = 'mail_password'
def clear_old_messages():

today = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%b-%Y')

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host=IMAP_HOST, ssl_context=ctx)
server.login(IMAP_USER, IMAP_PASS)
server.select()

resp, items = server.search(None, f"SENTBEFORE {today}")
items = items[0].split()
for i in items:
    server.store(i, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')

server.expunge()
    server.logout()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    clear_old_messages()
```

I've opened up crontab in Ubuntu with

```
crontab -e
```

and added

```
0 1 * * * /home/[user]/scripts/garbage.py
```

I'm a bit stymied as to what's not working. Do I need to call Python in the cron task, even though it's called at the top of the script? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The first thing I would do is add some logging (ex. `>/tmp/cron.log 2>&1`) - then you can examine the log for messages that might indicate why the command is failing

Comment: Famous mistake with cron : there is no env :: Edit the shebang `#!/bin/env python3` with the full path of python 3 binary. Find it with `whereis python3` The shebang could be something like `#!/usr/bin/python3.7` OR you can also call the python binary in the crontab file `0 1 * * * /usr/bin/python3.7  /home/[user]/scripts/garbage.py`

Comment: ... you will likely find that the error is something like `/bin/env: not found` because in Ubuntu, the `env` program is located at `/usr/bin/env`

Answer (score 1):

Famous mistake with cron : there is no env :: Edit the shebang `#!/bin/env python3` with the full path of python 3 binary. Find it with `whereis python3`

The shebang could be something like `#!/usr/bin/python3.7`

OR you can also call the python binary in the crontab file

```
0 1 * * * /usr/bin/python3.7  /home/[user]/scripts/garbage.py
```

Comment: Thanks for the help so far -- two issues have come up since: first, this method doesn't accommodate updates to Python -- it updated silently in the background yesterday, and I've started getting not found errors because it's now Python 3.8. Second, the Python instance I have found is in usr/lib, and while the script works with the updated shebang, the crontab script gives me a Permission Denied error for /usr/lib/python3.8.

Comment: ...a quick follow to say that using the python3.8 in usr/bin/ worked, it was just usr/lib that was giving me the permission denied. Still curious about an 'evergreen' script that doesn't break when Python versions update, though!